# How do I send a group MMS from the Yosemite Messages App when one user has iMessage?

Tags: mac, macos, messages, sms

I'm trying to send a group MMS message to a group of friends from my mac. Some are Android users and some are iMessage users. I can add all of them to the conversation from the mac, but as soon as I add an iPhone user, the entire thread automatically changes to an "iMessage" and I get the error "Your message could not be sent... xxx-xxx-xxxx is not registered with iMessage."

See image below for an example:

[image: Cannot send MMS to red # because I added blue #'s]

In this example, I can send an SMS to the red user. I can even send an MMS to a bunch of "red" users, but I cannot send an MMS to a group of "red" and "blue" users. As soon as the blue user is added, the entire thread changes to an iMessage and I get the error.

If, however, I start the thread on my phone, I can continue as an MMS from the Mac. Is this just a bug / limitation of the mac app? Thanks!